# Compatibility with .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: listlabel

I’m using, integrated in my software, List&Label 16 and now I would like to upgrade it to the version 24.
I have a couple of question:

1. I’m using, for historical reasons, .NET Framework 3.5, and I’m
   building my Visual Studio project with this framework. Can anyone
   confirm that List&Label 24 is fully compatible with .NET framework
   3.5?
2. Opening the LL viewer and editor from my application I cannot save any file in the C:\Program FIles… folder of my application. Should I change the folder? Or there is some workaround to write in one folder under the path C:\Program files…?

Thanks to all

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, LL24 is fully compatible with .NET 3.5
2. Basically, this is a Windows question. The viewer can open files from whatever location you have access to. There are several APIs in the product (e.g. `LlPreviewSetTempPath`) to set the temporary path for printing and exporting. On Windows 10, the default of your app should be somewhere in the Documents path of the user